# Polymorphically Dispatching in Java

Tags: java, double-dispatch

In the following, I want EventHandler to handle EventA one way, EventB another way, and any other Events (EventC, EventD) yet another way.  EventReceiver receives only a reference to an Event and calls EventHandler.handle().  The version that always gets called, of course, is EventHandler.handle(Event event).

Without using instanceOf, is there a way to polymorphically dispatch (perhaps via another method in EventHandler or generics) to the appropriate handle method?

```
class EventA extends Event {
}

class EventB extends Event {
}

class EventC extends Event {
}

class EventD extends Event {
}

class EventHandler {
    void handle(EventA event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventA");
    }

    void handle(EventB event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventB");
    }

    void handle(Event event) {
       System.out.println("Handling Event");
    }
}

class EventReceiver {
    private EventHandler handler;

    void receive(Event event) {
        handler.handle(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a case for applying (a variant of) the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). (In mainstream OO languages such as C++, C# and Java, methods are *single dispatch*, i.e. can only be polymorphic on one type at a time. Visitor allows one to implement *double dispatch*.)

This however requires that you be able to modify the `Event` classes as well, and creates a dependency from `Event`s to (a base interface of) `EventHandler`.

```
class EventA extends Event {
  public handleBy(EventHandler eh) {
    eh.handleEventA(this);
  }
}

class EventB extends Event {
  public handleBy(EventHandler eh) {
    eh.handleEventB(this);
  }
}

class EventHandler {
    void handleEventA(EventA event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventA");
    }

    void handleEventB(EventB event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventB");
    }

    void handle(Event event) {
       event.handleBy(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about the Visitor pattern and the acyclic Vistor pattern.  Unfortunately, I can't modify the Event class.  Moreover, I'll need to add many specialized Events over time.

Comment: Well, I guess since Java supports only single-dispatch, multiple-dispatch can only be kluged/mocked, as is done here and in the Visitor Wikipedia article. Also, I think the double-dispatch consists of 1) dispatching based on argument (kluged by function overloading in Java), and 2) standard polymorphism on the object the method is invoked...but in this case, `eh` is not polymorphic, so really we only have the 1) type dispatch here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for [double-dispatch](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleDispatchExample), no (which as one may indeed know is either called Visitor) ? I'll implement your example for EventA only

```
class Event {
    /**
     * Will do some type escalation
     */
    void handleWith(EventHandler care) {
        care.handle(this);
    }
}



class EventA extends Event {
    /**
     * As event is EventA, this implementation is called, with its correct type forced by the cast
     */
    void handleWith(EventHandler care) {
        care.handle((EventA) this);
    }
}

class EventHandler {
    /**
     * Finally comes here
     */
    void handle(EventA event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventA");
    }

    void handle(EventB event) {
       System.out.println("Handling EventB");
    }

    void handle(Event event) {
       System.out.println("Handling Event");
    }

    /**
     * Go here first and dispatch call to Event class
     */
    void doHandle(Event event) {
        event.handleWith(this);
    }
}

class EventReceiver {
    private EventHandler handler;

    void receive(Event event) {
        handler.doHandle(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java only has polymorphic dispatch on the object a method is invoked on. That means, the only way to get real polymorphism is to put the `handle()` method into the `Event` interface itself. I'd actually say that is the overall better and more OO solution, since a "handler" that operates on data objects is rather procedural.

Any other solution (like a map of handler objects keyed on the class) is going to be more complex and less flexible, especially concerning inheritance.

Comment: I agree Michael.  The Events, however, can be used in different context and will need to do things differently based on the context.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map and map event types to event handlers.

```
Map<Class<? extends Event>, Handler> map =
    new HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Handler>();

void receive(Event event) {
    Handler handler = map.get(event.getClass());
    handler.handle(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can do it with some pre-processing. Use something like this:

```
public abstract class EventHandler<T extends Event> {
   public abstract void handle(T event, Class<T> c);
   public abstract Class<T> handles();
}

public class EventHandlerA extends EventHandler<EventA> {
   @Override
   public void handle(EventA event, Class<EventA> c) {
      System.out.println(event);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<EventA> handles() {
      return EventA.class;
   }    
}
```

Then use a map to organize your handlers

```
HashMap<Class<?>,Collection<EventHandler<?>> handlers;
```

When an event needs to be handled just retrieve the handlers from the map. If Class.equals() and Class.hashCode() doesn't work how you want then you'll need a wrapper to get the behavior you want.