# Design pattern for calling different functions for different instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I have a java code like this-

```
Sample obj;
if(obj instanceOf Class1) 
{
    method1(obj);
} else if(obj instanceOf Class2) 
{
    method2(obj);
} else if(obj instanceOf Class3) 
{
    method3(obj);
}
```

*Class1*, *Class2* and *Class3* are actually DTO's and they are children of *Sample*, so I don't want to write business logic in DTO's.

I want to write the logic of *method1*, *mehtod2* and *method3* in a different class. Is there a design pattern for that. 
I am using spring MVC.

Basically, I am looking for some non-java technique to call the appropriate based on the instance instead of checking with instanceOf every single time.

Comment: Who is calling `methodn(...)`? Are they in some shared service or al of them are in `Sample`?

Comment: @J-Alex : these are just private methods in the current class, for now. But I want to move them to different classes in an organised manner.

Comment: what is the current class? Is it some `spring service` or what?

Comment: @J-Alex: yes. It is a spring service.

Comment: As Java does not support double dispatch, the Visitor pattern is often proposed as an alternative e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4737350/1356423

Answer (score 2):

Define a `method` interface and implement the common interface in `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3` - delegate to `method1`, `method2` or `method3` as appropriate in the implementation in those classes. Program to the common interface.

```
obj.method();
```

Comment: Class1, Class2 and Class3 are actually DTO's and they are children of Sample, so I don't want to write business login in DTO's. I'll update the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good one but let's try

- Create an Interface

  public interface Processor {

  ```
  void process(Simple simple);
  ```

  }
- Write implementation for each subclass of Sample
  // Class1 Processor
  public class Class1Processor implements Processor {

  ```
  @Override
  public void process(Simple simple) {
      System.out.println("Class1 processing completed");
  }
  ```

  }
  // Class2 Processor
  public class Class2Processor implements Processor {

  ```
  @Override
  public void process(Simple simple) {
      System.out.println("Class2 processing completed");
  }
  ```

  }
- Processor Factory Class
  public class ProcessorFactory {

  ```
  private static final Map<Class<? extends Simple>, Processor> LOOKUP = new HashMap<>();

  static {
      LOOKUP.put(Class1.class, new Class1Processor());
      LOOKUP.put(Class2.class, new Class2Processor());
  }

  public static <T extends Simple> Processor getProcessor(T obj) {
      return LOOKUP.get(obj.getClass());
  }
  ```

  }
- And Lastly Main Class
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  ```
  Simple class1 = new Class1();
  Simple class2 = new Class2();

  ProcessorFactory.getProcessor(class1).process(class1);
  ProcessorFactory.getProcessor(class2).process(class2);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

How about create a custom annotation for classes? Does this solve your problem about business logic etc. 
Something like

```
@CustomMethodName(method="method1")
public class Class1{
 //..
}
@CustomMethodName(method="method2")
public class Class2{
 //..
}
@CustomMethodName(method="method3")
public class Class3{
 //..
}
```

After you should get your method name by using

```
Class<?> aClass = Sample.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();
for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof CustomMethodName){
        CustomMethodName myAnnotation = (CustomMethodName) annotation;
        String methodName = myAnnotation.method();
        java.lang.reflect.Method method;
        try {
           method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);// get method wherever you define them
           method.invoke(obj);//execute method
        } catch (SecurityException e) { ... }
          catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { ... }
     }
}
```

Comment: exactly. I am looking for something along these lines. I just want it with less Java and more spring xml configurations.

Comment: It might be messy than old way, I would prefer instanceof by the way though :)