# Super class method and submethods for subclasses in runtime

Tags: java, java-8

I have method with super class as argument in main class.

```
public class MainClass() {
...
    public void myMethod(MyClass class)
...
```

In runtime this object can be any of its subclasses and it should call different method depending on subclasses in same main class

```
public class MainClass() {
...
    public void mySubMethod(MySubClass1 class)

    public void mySubMethod(MuySubClass2 class)
...
```

Of course, I can use instanceOf or Static Factory Pattern with Enum but still it will be (pseudo code)

```
public void myMethod(MyClass class) {
if (instanceOf == MySubclass1) mySubMethod((MySubClass1)subClass1Object)
if (instanceOf == MySubclass2) mySubMethod((MySubClass2)subClass2Object)
}
```

In runtime jvm knows which subclass exactly object is and knows for each sub-method argument should be. I don't have control over MyClass, MySubclass1 and MySubclass2,...

But is there any elegant way to achive this?

Comment: Why not simply overload `myMethod()`?

Comment: @ernest_k overloading only works on static types, it is not dispatched dynamically.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737350/polymorphically-dispatching-in-java

Comment: @Thilo The OP doesn't mention that the object is created dynamically. It's possible that this "problem" is a result of how `myMethod` is currently declared. Maybe it can change.

Comment: Object are created dynamically. It depends what I get from other method.

Comment: You code would be much more readable if you didn’t use the keyword `class` as (invalid) parameter name throughout your code.

Comment: Sorry, it was pseudo-code. I send object. I get object in generic way, as super class upcast object of one of its sub class. In fact it is abstract class. And then I should call one of two methods. One method accept one subclass as variable, and other method the other subclass as variable. JVM knows which exactly subclass upcasted object is.
I just want to do it without switch and anything similar to instanceof, if there is more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "double-dispatch" by moving those methods to the various target subclasses themselves.

```
interface MyClass {
   void mySubMethod(Something context);
}

public void myMethod(MyClass target){
   target.mySubMethod(this);
}
```

Comment: I updated situation. Point is that I don't have control over MyClass and MySubclassN. This would be good solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is to use HandlerFactories

```
public class HandlerRegistry {
  public void registerHandler(Class classToHandle, HandlerFactory handler)
  // returns the proper handler (via the HandlerFactory) for the registered class
  public Handler getHandlerFor(Class classToHandle)
}
```

You can make the methods in this class static or use the Singleton pattern to make the HandlerRgistry accessible everywhere
    }

Comment: Can you explain little bit more with this, please?

Comment: MySubclass1, MySubclass2... each subclass can register an instance of Handler that defines what to do/what to call on the subclass